# Remove colons (:) from illustration index in Microsoft Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, find-and-replace, table-of-contents

How can I remove all the **:** from illustration index in Word 2010?

```
FIG. 2.4: Representação em RDF/XML da  FIG. 2.3 27
FIG. 2.5: Ilustração da Utilização do RDF com o RDFS    28
```

But I need this:

```
FIG. 2.4 Representação em RDF/XML da  FIG. 2.3  27
FIG. 2.5 Ilustração da Utilização do RDF com o RDFS 28
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft has an article on it [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/find-and-replace-text-or-other-items-HP005189433.aspx)

Objective: Do a find and replace.
You can automatically replace text — for example, you can replace ":" with ""

1. On the **Edit** menu, click **Replace**.
2. In the **Find what** box, enter the text that you want to search for(":").
3. In the **Replace with** box, enter the replacement text("")
4. Select any other options that you want (in this case, N/A).
   Click **Find Next**, **Replace**, or **Replace All**.

What this does, is it looks for all colons (":") and replaces them with "" (or nothing) thereby removing all colons.

Comment: Press CTRL + F to bring up the "find" dialog box.

Comment: Press `CTRL+H` instead, to go straight to the "Replace" dialog box.  It's a common standard keyboard accelerator for it.

Comment: add-info: select "only the text" of illustration index and after CRTL+H

Comment: @celsowm I'm not sure what you mean, Click "edit" under my question, and fix-it.  If it still makes sense, I'll approve it.

Answer (score 4):

Type `CTRL+H` and type **:** in the top box and nothing in the second box and then press `Replace All`.

This is the same for a lot of Windows text editors as well.

Comment: add-info: select "only the text" of illustration index and after CRTL+H